# Global Realm Object: Singleton or Fetch It Every Time?

Tags: swift, realm, singleton

In my app I need to have global access to a `currentUser` which is an instance of a `User` class defined like this:

```
class User: Object{
  @objc dynamic var recordName = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var email = ""
  @objc dynamic var photo: Data? = nil

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "recordName"
  }
}
```

The `currentUser` is established when the app launches, and I refer to it frequently almost everywhere in my app.

I've noticed that from time-to-time, I get an error that appears to be caused by referencing this `currentUser` in different places:

> Realm accessed from incorrect thread

I'm able to keep track of which thread Realm is on most of the time, but it's difficult to cover all cases. So this leads me to my question.

Is there a safe way to set the `currentUser` object once as a singleton? Or should I save their ID to disk and then fetch the object from Realm every time I need it (something like below)?

```
let realm = try! Realm()
if let currentUserId = defaults.string(forKey: "currentUserId"), let user = realm.object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: currentUserId){
  currentUser = user
}
```

I am using Swift 4.2 on Xcode 10. Thanks!

Comment: Well you need to retrieve it per thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can make sure that you always access your `currentUser` object from the same thread, it's fine to set it up as a globally accessible object once and use that auto-updating reference to it instead of re-fetching it every time from Realm.

You can achieve this by either creating a dedicated thread to Realm and always dispatching to that thread before accessing Realm/`currentUser` or simply doing it from a system thread, such as `DispatchQueue.main`.

Comment: I agree and would add that if you have just a single singleton in your app (say, called DependencyManager) for the purpose of hanging all other global objects from it, you'd be able to do dependency injection such that unit tests could access the singleton and replace any property (any of the objects) with a mock object.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much!