# Is it fine to make DAO layer (of realm OR coredata) as singleton for multi-threaded application?

Tags: ios, core-data, realm

Is it fine to make DAO layer (of realm and coredata) as singleton for multi-threaded application?

most of the time we make DAOLayer singleton, as we want to access it through out an app. don't want that many instance of DAOLayer floating around.

but as we know coredata and realm both are not thread safe. So in that case is if an instance is singleton, each time it will refer to same object. may be not fine for multi-threaded app.

how to deal with multi-threading with DAOLayer (common framework kind of thing).

Comment: Realm itself is thread safe. Accessing the same objects on different threads is not thread safe but there are ways around that; using a ThreadSafeReference for example; `let personRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: person)`. Can you provide a specific example of what you're trying to do as it's a bit vague - perhaps some code as to what the issue is? See an excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993983/global-realm-object-singleton-or-fetch-it-every-time/52994112#52994112)

Comment: i wanted to design singleton DAOLayer for realm CRUD and fetch query operations.

Comment: If that's the goal, then write some code and if you get stuck, let us know. Singletons are pretty common with Realm.

Comment: No, you have to use a thread local instance on each thread.

Answer (score 0):

> So in that case is if an instance is singleton, each time it will refer to same object. may be not fine for multi-threaded app.

This will happen every time if you refer to a variable using multi-threading. There is no problem for your singleton DAO, as long as your layer are immutable from outside layers. Some of the multi-threading problems refers to a changes in the instances.

Many people don't like the Rober C. Martin Clean Architecture, but in [this post](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) he says something correct:

> The overriding rule that makes this architecture work is The Dependency Rule. This rule says that source code dependencies can only point inwards. Nothing in an inner circle can know anything at all about something in an outer circle. In particular, the name of something declared in an outer circle must not be mentioned by the code in the an inner circle. That includes, functions, classes. variables, or any other named software entity.